# Clipping with results going to existing feature class using arcpy.Clip_analysis()?

Tags: arcpy, clip, append

I am using `arcpy.Clip_analysis()` in arcpy immediate window to clip feature. This function creates new object as a result of clipping. That take more processing time. Can I do the clipping and save the clipped object to an existing feature class?

My sample code:

```
arcpy.Clip_Analysis("Road", "clipRectangle", "D:\output.gdb\road2")
```

Now, some of the suggestions below is to use "in_memory" to clip faster by writing to the RAM instead of hard disk. I tried the following:

```
arcpy.Clip_Analysis("Road", "clipRectangle", "in_memory\road2")
```

That works fine, but now I will have again to write them in the hard disk to have them saved. Wont that be the same as if I clip directly to hard disk as first code?

Is that the only way or there are some other approaches that can do faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will see from the [Clip help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm) a value for the `out_feature_class` parameter is mandatory and is:

> The feature class to be created.

Since you want the output of a [Clip](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm) to be appended to or merged into an existing feature class, and you have tagged your question as ArcPy, I recommend that you write a short script that clips followed by an [Append](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm) or [Merge](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm).

As [commented by @BERA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251958/clipping-to-an-existing-feature-class/251960#comment396603_251958):

> If you dont want the results to be written to disk you can use the
>   in-memory workspace which is faster:
>   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm

I think that is well worth considering. I think you should proceed to test merging/appending to the existing feature classes stored in_memory and/or in standard workspaces to see what works best for you.